# How to Debug FAST Search Query?

Tags: sharepoint-enterprise, query, managed-property, fast-for-sharepoint, crawled-property

We have a SharePoint 2010 Farm with a SharePoint FAST Search Server.

My problem is if you search in the list "Telefonbuch" for the user Manfred Willy through the query "Willy" the search shows two results: Manfred Willy as desired and Ursula Dachs.

It doesn't matter if I search for firstname "Manfred" or lastname "Willy" or both, the search shows the result "Ursula Dachs" also.

So I take a look at the list entry of Ursula Dachs, but I don't find any columns in the list item where "Manfred" or "Willy" is set.

In the next step I searched for managed properties. For the query "Lastname:Willy" I get the right result, only Manfred Willy is shown.
For the query "Firstname:Manfred" only entries are shown which has the firstname Manfred, Ursula Dachs isn't shown.
So I think there are managed properties that have the value "Manfred" and "Willy" in the list entry of Ursula Dachs. But I can't find them.

I also deleted the list entry for Ursula Dachs and Manfred Willy from the index and recrawled it, but the problem wasn't resolved.

To get the crawled properties from both items I activate the FDDumper and recrawl both items. So I get FFD Logs from both items.

Log for Ursula Dachs:

```
4 opid i 174587
5 docid s12 ssic://97289
10 collection s2 sp
2 op s3 ADD
A
42 49691C90-7E17-101A-A91C-08002B2ECDA9:#9:31 s62 http://suche.de/Lists/Telefonbuch/DispForm.aspx?ID=390
58 00130329-0000-0130-C000-000000131346:ows_TelefonbuchFax:31 s4 2599
53 00130329-0000-0130-C000-000000131346:ows_LinkTitle:31 s17 Ursula Dachs
12 LastModified s27 2015-09-10T05:00:49,0000000
46 00130329-0000-0130-C000-000000131346:ows_ID:20 s3 390
58 00130329-0000-0130-C000-000000131346:ows_ItemChildCount:31 s1 0
56 00140329-0000-0140-C000-000000141446:DAV:contentclass:31 s24 STS_ListItem_GenericList
56 00130329-0000-0130-C000-000000131346:ows_AuthorUserId:31 s2 42
43 B725F130-47EF-101A-A5F1-02608C9EEBAC:#15:64 s27 2014-05-25T21:21:28,0000000
44 012357BD-1113-171D-1F25-292BB0B0B0B0:#325:20 s20 -2052350468597448428
63 00130329-0000-0130-C000-000000131346:ows_TelefonbuchNachname:31 s10 Dachs
3 url s62 http://suche.de/Lists/Telefonbuch/DispForm.aspx?ID=390
64 158D7563-AEFF-4DBF-BF16-4A1445F0366C:ows_taxId_SPLocationList:31 s38 {26ad4c67-d9f6-4a02-ba27-4387ebfec86c}
42 F29F85E0-4FF9-1068-AB91-08002B27B3D9:#8:31 s9 admsp2010
59 00130329-0000-0130-C000-000000131346:ows_TelefonbuchName:31 s17 Ursula Dachs
4 size s1 0
55 0B63E343-9CCC-11D0-BCDB-00805FCCCE04:EmbeddedContent:31 s13 DispForm.aspx
60 00130329-0000-0130-C000-000000131346:ows__UIVersionString:31 s3 1.0
62 00130329-0000-0130-C000-000000131346:ows_TelefonbuchVorname:31 s6 Ursula
59 00130329-0000-0130-C000-000000131346:ows_TelefonbuchRaum:31 s5 W-407
52 00130329-0000-0130-C000-000000131346:ows_Modified:64 s27 2015-09-10T05:00:49,0000000
11 isdirectory s5 false
44 012357BD-1113-171D-1F25-292BB0B0B0B0:#324:20 s19 1144039826440624687
50 00130329-0000-0130-C000-000000131346:ows_isItem:11 s4 true
43 012357BD-1113-171D-1F25-292BB0B0B0B0:#98:19 s1 6
50 00130329-0000-0130-C000-000000131346:SecurityId:31 s38 {072F75B8-F6F8-4E6E-B2C7-AB90E11C57E4}
53 00130329-0000-0130-C000-000000131346:ows_SPSiteURL:31 s23 http://suche.de
96 0B63E350-9CCC-11D0-BCDB-00805FCCCE04:urn:schemas.microsoft.com:fulltextqueryinfo:displaytitle:31 s17 Ursula Dachs
42 012357BD-1113-171D-1F25-292BB0B0B0B0:#4:64 L3 s27 2015-09-10T05:00:49,0000000 s27 2015-09-10T05:00:49,0000000 s27 2015-09-10T05:00:49,0000000
44 012357BD-1113-171D-1F25-292BB0B0B0B0:#104:31 s36 0c37852b-34d0-418e-91c6-2ac25af4be5b
44 012357BD-1113-171D-1F25-292BB0B0B0B0:#170:19 s1 9
20 @@@:)protocolhandler s4 SSIC
60 00130329-0000-0130-C000-000000131346:ows_FolderChildCount:31 s1 0
66 00130329-0000-0130-C000-000000131346:ows_TelefonbuchAnmeldename:31 s18 Test\dachs
56 00130329-0000-0130-C000-000000131346:ows_DocumentLink:31 s50 http://suche.de/Lists/Telefonbuch/390_.000
55 00130329-0000-0130-C000-000000131346:ows_ContentType:31 s18 Person oder Gruppe
60 00130329-0000-0130-C000-000000131346:ows_TelefonbuchEmail:31 s24 Ursula.Dachs@test.de
65 00130329-0000-0130-C000-000000131346:ows_TelefonbuchOrgEinheit:31 s5 I-FIN
59 00130329-0000-0130-C000-000000131346:ows_LinkTitleNoMenu:31 s17 Ursula Dachs
42 F29F85E0-4FF9-1068-AB91-08002B27B3D9:#2:31 s17 Ursula Dachs
43 B725F130-47EF-101A-A5F1-02608C9EEBAC:#14:64 L2 s27 2015-09-10T05:00:49,0000000 s27 2015-09-10T05:00:49,0000000
65 00130329-0000-0130-C000-000000131346:ows_TelefonbuchFunktTitel:31 s13 Mitarbeiterin
21 @@@:)propertiesfeeder s15 canonical names
43 0B63E343-9CCC-11D0-BCDB-00805FCCCE04:#19:11 s4 true
42 0B63E343-9CCC-11D0-BCDB-00805FCCCE04:#4:31 s23 http://suche.de
51 00130329-0000-0130-C000-000000131346:ows_ItemURL:31 s50 http://suche.de/Lists/Telefonbuch/390_.000
53 0B63E343-9CCC-11D0-BCDB-00805FCCCE04:FileExtension:31 s4 ASPX
44 012357BD-1113-171D-1F25-292BB0B0B0B0:#326:20 s10 3645774427
62 00130329-0000-0130-C000-000000131346:ows_TelefonbuchTelefon:31 s4 2675
52 00130329-0000-0130-C000-000000131346:ows_SiteName:31 s5 Suche
44 012357BD-1113-171D-1F25-292BB0B0B0B0:#315:31 s5 Suche
44 012357BD-1113-171D-1F25-292BB0B0B0B0:#323:64 s27 2015-09-10T12:32:28,3923405
42 F29F85E0-4FF9-1068-AB91-08002B27B3D9:#4:31 s9 adm
50 00130329-0000-0130-C000-000000131346:ows_SiteID:31 s38 {6310e291-a886-4670-927d-c8473e852d31}
64 158D7563-AEFF-4DBF-BF16-4A1445F0366C:ows_taxId_SPLocationSite:31 s23 http://suche.de
8 docaclms s1641 O:S-1-5-21-3644388107-1047395450-350737637-36313G:DUD:(A;;FA;;;LS)(A;;FA;;;S-1-5-21-3644388107-1047395450-350737637-36313)(A;;FA;;;S-1-5-21-3644388107-1047395450-350737637-40874)(A;;FA;;;S-1-5-21-3644388107-1047395450-350737637-36625)(A;;FA;;;S-1-5-21-3644388107-1047395450-350737637-36302)(A;;FA;;;S-1-5-21-3644388107-1047395450-350737637-36635)(A;;FA;;;S-1-5-21-3644388107-1047395450-350737637-36626)(A;;FA;;;S-1-5-21-3644388107-1047395450-350737637-36294)(A;;FA;;;S-1-5-21-3644388107-1047395450-350737637-36293)(A;;FA;;;S-1-5-21-3644388107-1047395450-350737637-38290)(A;;FA;;;S-1-5-21-3644388107-1047395450-350737637-18405)(A;;FA;;;S-1-5-21-3644388107-1047395450-350737637-37213)(A;;FA;;;S-1-5-21-3644388107-1047395450-350737637-36927)(A;;FA;;;S-1-5-21-3644388107-1047395450-350737637-36651)(A;;FA;;;S-1-5-21-3644388107-1047395450-350737637-36711)(A;;FA;;;S-1-5-21-3644388107-1047395450-350737637-39482)(A;;FA;;;AU)(A;;FA;;;S-1-5-21-3644388107-1047395450-350737637-40021)(A;;FA;;;S-1-5-21-3644388107-1047395450-350737637-37062)(A;;FA;;;S-1-5-21-3644388107-1047395450-350737637-36933)(A;;FA;;;S-1-5-21-3644388107-1047395450-350737637-2896)(A;;FA;;;S-1-5-21-3644388107-1047395450-350737637-2770)(A;;FA;;;S-1-5-21-3644388107-1047395450-350737637-1743)(A;;FA;;;S-1-5-21-3644388107-1047395450-350737637-1789)(A;;FA;;;S-1-5-21-3644388107-1047395450-350737637-26410)(A;;FA;;;S-1-5-21-3644388107-1047395450-350737637-2607)(A;;FA;;;S-1-5-21-3644388107-1047395450-350737637-27918)(A;;FA;;;S-1-5-21-3644388107-1047395450-350737637-24778)(A;;FA;;;S-1-5-21-3644388107-1047395450-350737637-40103)(A;;FA;;;S-1-5-21-3644388107-1047395450-350737637-33455)
56 00020329-0000-0000-C000-000000000046:DAV:iscollection:11 s5 false
43 B725F130-47EF-101A-A5F1-02608C9EEBAC:#10:31 s17 Ursula Dachs
64 158D7563-AEFF-4DBF-BF16-4A1445F0366C:ows_taxId_SPLocationInfo:31 s66 http://suche.de|{26ad4c67-d9f6-4a02-ba27-4387ebfec86c}|390
94 00020329-0000-0000-C000-000000000046:urn:schemas.microsoft.com:sharepoint:portal:isdocument:20 s1 0
E
```

Log for Manfred Willy:

```
4 opid i 173898
5 docid s12 ssic://36976
10 collection s2 sp
2 op s3 ADD
A
42 49691C90-7E17-101A-A91C-08002B2ECDA9:#9:31 s62 http://suche/Lists/Telefonbuch/DispForm.aspx?ID=152
58 00130329-0000-0130-C000-000000131346:ows_TelefonbuchFax:31 s4 3026
53 00130329-0000-0130-C000-000000131346:ows_LinkTitle:31 s18 Manfred Willy
12 LastModified s27 2015-09-10T05:00:12,0000000
46 00130329-0000-0130-C000-000000131346:ows_ID:20 s3 152
58 00130329-0000-0130-C000-000000131346:ows_ItemChildCount:31 s1 0
56 00140329-0000-0140-C000-000000141446:DAV:contentclass:31 s24 STS_ListItem_GenericList
56 00130329-0000-0130-C000-000000131346:ows_AuthorUserId:31 s2 42
43 B725F130-47EF-101A-A5F1-02608C9EEBAC:#15:64 s27 2014-05-25T21:20:48,0000000
44 012357BD-1113-171D-1F25-292BB0B0B0B0:#325:20 s20 -1762176426184682535
63 00130329-0000-0130-C000-000000131346:ows_TelefonbuchNachname:31 s10 Willy
3 url s62 http://suche/Lists/Telefonbuch/DispForm.aspx?ID=152
64 158D7563-AEFF-4DBF-BF16-4A1445F0366C:ows_taxId_SPLocationList:31 s38 {26ad4c67-d9f6-4a02-ba27-4387ebfec86c}
42 F29F85E0-4FF9-1068-AB91-08002B27B3D9:#8:31 s9 admsp2010
59 00130329-0000-0130-C000-000000131346:ows_TelefonbuchName:31 s18 Manfred Willy
4 size s1 0
55 0B63E343-9CCC-11D0-BCDB-00805FCCCE04:EmbeddedContent:31 s13 DispForm.aspx
60 00130329-0000-0130-C000-000000131346:ows__UIVersionString:31 s3 1.0
62 00130329-0000-0130-C000-000000131346:ows_TelefonbuchVorname:31 s7 Manfred
59 00130329-0000-0130-C000-000000131346:ows_TelefonbuchRaum:31 s6 KL-003
52 00130329-0000-0130-C000-000000131346:ows_Modified:64 s27 2015-09-10T05:00:12,0000000
11 isdirectory s5 false
44 012357BD-1113-171D-1F25-292BB0B0B0B0:#324:20 s19 1567554748486940127
50 00130329-0000-0130-C000-000000131346:ows_isItem:11 s4 true
43 012357BD-1113-171D-1F25-292BB0B0B0B0:#98:19 s1 6
50 00130329-0000-0130-C000-000000131346:SecurityId:31 s38 {072F75B8-F6F8-4E6E-B2C7-AB90E11C57E4}
53 00130329-0000-0130-C000-000000131346:ows_SPSiteURL:31 s23 http://suche.de
96 0B63E350-9CCC-11D0-BCDB-00805FCCCE04:urn:schemas.microsoft.com:fulltextqueryinfo:displaytitle:31 s18 Manfred Willy
42 012357BD-1113-171D-1F25-292BB0B0B0B0:#4:64 L3 s27 2015-09-10T05:00:12,0000000 s27 2015-09-10T05:00:12,0000000 s27 2015-09-10T05:00:12,0000000
44 012357BD-1113-171D-1F25-292BB0B0B0B0:#104:31 s36 0c37852b-34d0-418e-91c6-2ac25af4be5b
44 012357BD-1113-171D-1F25-292BB0B0B0B0:#170:19 s1 9
20 @@@:)protocolhandler s4 SSIC
60 00130329-0000-0130-C000-000000131346:ows_FolderChildCount:31 s1 0
66 00130329-0000-0130-C000-000000131346:ows_TelefonbuchAnmeldename:31 s18 test\willy
56 00130329-0000-0130-C000-000000131346:ows_DocumentLink:31 s50 http://suche/Lists/Telefonbuch/152_.000
55 00130329-0000-0130-C000-000000131346:ows_ContentType:31 s18 Person oder Gruppe
60 00130329-0000-0130-C000-000000131346:ows_TelefonbuchEmail:31 s25 Manfred.Willy@test.de
65 00130329-0000-0130-C000-000000131346:ows_TelefonbuchOrgEinheit:31 s5 I-PRO
59 00130329-0000-0130-C000-000000131346:ows_LinkTitleNoMenu:31 s18 Manfred Willy
42 F29F85E0-4FF9-1068-AB91-08002B27B3D9:#2:31 s18 Manfred Willy
43 B725F130-47EF-101A-A5F1-02608C9EEBAC:#14:64 L2 s27 2015-09-10T05:00:12,0000000 s27 2015-09-10T05:00:12,0000000
65 00130329-0000-0130-C000-000000131346:ows_TelefonbuchFunktTitel:31 s11 Mitarbeiter
21 @@@:)propertiesfeeder s15 canonical names
43 0B63E343-9CCC-11D0-BCDB-00805FCCCE04:#19:11 s4 true
42 0B63E343-9CCC-11D0-BCDB-00805FCCCE04:#4:31 s23 http://suche.de
51 00130329-0000-0130-C000-000000131346:ows_ItemURL:31 s50 http://suche/Lists/Telefonbuch/152_.000
53 0B63E343-9CCC-11D0-BCDB-00805FCCCE04:FileExtension:31 s4 ASPX
44 012357BD-1113-171D-1F25-292BB0B0B0B0:#326:20 s10 3645774427
62 00130329-0000-0130-C000-000000131346:ows_TelefonbuchTelefon:31 s4 2545
52 00130329-0000-0130-C000-000000131346:ows_SiteName:31 s5 Suche
44 012357BD-1113-171D-1F25-292BB0B0B0B0:#315:31 s5 Suche
44 012357BD-1113-171D-1F25-292BB0B0B0B0:#323:64 s27 2015-09-10T12:42:28,5329655
42 F29F85E0-4FF9-1068-AB91-08002B27B3D9:#4:31 s9 adm
50 00130329-0000-0130-C000-000000131346:ows_SiteID:31 s38 {6310e291-a886-4670-927d-c8473e852d31}
64 158D7563-AEFF-4DBF-BF16-4A1445F0366C:ows_taxId_SPLocationSite:31 s23 http://suche.de
8 docaclms s1641 O:S-1-5-21-3644388107-1047395450-350737637-36313G:DUD:(A;;FA;;;LS)(A;;FA;;;S-1-5-21-3644388107-1047395450-350737637-36313)(A;;FA;;;S-1-5-21-3644388107-1047395450-350737637-40874)(A;;FA;;;S-1-5-21-3644388107-1047395450-350737637-36625)(A;;FA;;;S-1-5-21-3644388107-1047395450-350737637-36302)(A;;FA;;;S-1-5-21-3644388107-1047395450-350737637-36635)(A;;FA;;;S-1-5-21-3644388107-1047395450-350737637-36626)(A;;FA;;;S-1-5-21-3644388107-1047395450-350737637-36294)(A;;FA;;;S-1-5-21-3644388107-1047395450-350737637-36293)(A;;FA;;;S-1-5-21-3644388107-1047395450-350737637-38290)(A;;FA;;;S-1-5-21-3644388107-1047395450-350737637-18405)(A;;FA;;;S-1-5-21-3644388107-1047395450-350737637-37213)(A;;FA;;;S-1-5-21-3644388107-1047395450-350737637-36927)(A;;FA;;;S-1-5-21-3644388107-1047395450-350737637-36651)(A;;FA;;;S-1-5-21-3644388107-1047395450-350737637-36711)(A;;FA;;;S-1-5-21-3644388107-1047395450-350737637-39482)(A;;FA;;;AU)(A;;FA;;;S-1-5-21-3644388107-1047395450-350737637-40021)(A;;FA;;;S-1-5-21-3644388107-1047395450-350737637-37062)(A;;FA;;;S-1-5-21-3644388107-1047395450-350737637-36933)(A;;FA;;;S-1-5-21-3644388107-1047395450-350737637-2896)(A;;FA;;;S-1-5-21-3644388107-1047395450-350737637-2770)(A;;FA;;;S-1-5-21-3644388107-1047395450-350737637-1743)(A;;FA;;;S-1-5-21-3644388107-1047395450-350737637-1789)(A;;FA;;;S-1-5-21-3644388107-1047395450-350737637-26410)(A;;FA;;;S-1-5-21-3644388107-1047395450-350737637-2607)(A;;FA;;;S-1-5-21-3644388107-1047395450-350737637-27918)(A;;FA;;;S-1-5-21-3644388107-1047395450-350737637-24778)(A;;FA;;;S-1-5-21-3644388107-1047395450-350737637-40103)(A;;FA;;;S-1-5-21-3644388107-1047395450-350737637-33455)
56 00020329-0000-0000-C000-000000000046:DAV:iscollection:11 s5 false
43 B725F130-47EF-101A-A5F1-02608C9EEBAC:#10:31 s18 Manfred Willy
64 158D7563-AEFF-4DBF-BF16-4A1445F0366C:ows_taxId_SPLocationInfo:31 s66 http://suche.de|{26ad4c67-d9f6-4a02-ba27-4387ebfec86c}|152
94 00020329-0000-0000-C000-000000000046:urn:schemas.microsoft.com:sharepoint:portal:isdocument:20 s1 0
E
```

My suspicion is that in the index for the list entry Ursula Dachs have to be the values "Manfred" and "Willy". Are there Tools to debug the query process?

Anyone have an idea why Ursula Dachs is shown by the search for "Manfred Willy" and how I can resolve this problem.

Best Regards,
Dominik V.

Comment: Deleted the list item from Ursula Dachs. Rerun the script for the telephonebook sync . Crawl the content source. And the problem was resolved.